# Soap PHP : double XML tag

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

Hye

I'm trying to use a WebService with SOAP in PHP. But the SoapVar creates my DOM XML with double XML tag

My code :

```
$xmlContent = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:com="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Commun.Metier">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <tem:SendData> ....';
$soapClient = new SoapClient("URL OF THE WSDL", array('trace' => 1, 'location' => 'URL OF THE SERVICE', 'uri' => 'URL OF THE SERVICE'));
$myXML = new SoapVar($xmlContent, XSD_ANYXML);

try {
        $result = $soapClient->__soapCall("SendData", array('SendData' => $myXML));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }
```

The problem is that I have an exception Bad request because the XML I'm sending haves 2 XML tags and Soap Enveloppe :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:com="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Commun.Metier">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <tem:SendData>
```

How can I cancel this double tag ?

Thanks